# Magento 2 app/code and app/design difference

Tags: magento2

I'm curious what should be the proper way of using these two folders. Normally when I create my own module. I include everything *(php, phtml, css, js, images)* under my app/code module. Which somehow works and easy to navigate into.

But I have a feeling I'm misusing this. Can someone enlighten me? Can't find anything from the documentation discussing how this two directories should be treated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/prepare/prepare_file-str.html) will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main different of app/code and app/design is the when we developed our own module which can define in app/code and when we developed our own theme we can use the app/design that is the main different between this two.

simple thing is for **custom module development** use app/code and **custom theme creation** use app/design.